# drupal 6 import module lose first symbol in some word in CSV file after import

Tags: drupal, import, drupal-6

import moduleof Drupal 6  lose first symbol in some word in CSV file after import. In CSV file "word", but after import - "ord".

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. This question might be better suited to drupal.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I ask my question to this site.

Comment: Also, you should be aware that Drupal 6 is no longer supported.  Any sites on Drupal 6 should migrate to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.

Comment: tnanks, but i found this error